# Python Marshal Pydroid

Tags: python, unmarshalling, pydroid

Hi i have a code with python the code works in pydroid 3 succesful but when i try code on my pc it says

```
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

its not special for this code i cant work any codes like this in python but i can run in pydroid 3 successful

my question is how can i use this code in my pc or how can i decode this type of codes

code example:

```
import marshal
exec(marshal.loads(b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00s|\x00\x00\x00d\x00d\x01l\x00Z\x00d\x02Z\x01e\x02e\x01\x83\x01\x01\x00e\x03d\x03\x83\x01Z\x04e\x05e\x04\x83\x01\xa0\x06\xa1\x00Z\x07e\x08e\x07d\x04d\x05\x83\x03Z\te\x00\xa0\ne\t\xa1\x01Z\x0be\x05d\x06d\x07\x83\x02Z\x0ce\x0c\xa0\rd\x08\xa1\x01\x01\x00e\x0c\xa0\rd\te\x0ee\x0b\x83\x01\x17\x00d\n\x17\x00\xa1\x01\x01\x00e\x0c\xa0\x0f\xa1\x00\x01\x00e\x02d\x0b\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x01S\x00)\x0c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x00Nz\xe9\n\n  ___ __ _  ___ __ _  ___ _ __ __ _  ___| | __\n / __/ _` |/ __/ _` |/ __| \'__/ _` |/ __| |/ /\n| (_| (_| | (_| (_| | (__| | | (_| | (__|   <\n \\___\\__,_|\\___\\__,_|\\___|_|  \\__,_|\\___|_|\\_|\n Youtube : CACACRACK\n Instagram: jeager000\n z\x0fMasukan File : \xda\x00\xda\x04execz\x08hasil.py\xda\x01wz\x0fimport marshal\nz\x13exec(marshal.loads(z\x02))z"selesai, nama file kamu : hasil.py)\x10\xda\x07marshal\xda\tcacacrack\xda\x05print\xda\x05input\xda\x03inp\xda\x04open\xda\x04read\xda\x04file\xda\x07compile\xda\x03com\xda\x05dumps\xda\x03dum\xda\x08file_out\xda\x05write\xda\x04repr\xda\x05close\xa9\x00r\x15\x00\x00\x00r\x15\x00\x00\x00r\x02\x00\x00\x00\xda\x08<module>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x16\x00\x00\x00\x08\x02\x04\t\x08\x01\x08\x01\x0c\x01\x0c\x01\n\x01\n\x01\n\x01\x16\x01\x08\x02'))
```

I tried program on pydroid 3 it worked well but it didnt work on my pc python 3.10

Comment: I dont think you should run this line, anyway? What is this? `Youtube : CACACRACK`? `Instagram: jeager000`? That has nothing to to with PyDroid

Comment: its not about this code this type of code i can't use them its not special for this pls i just wanna use this types of codes

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, `marshal` isn't made for such data exchange (incompatible changes may occur), better use `pickle`.